# My Minecraft skin won't show for others

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This has been happening for a while, I've noticed that whenever I'm playing Minecraft with my brothers, (On LAN, I'm not sure if it works on public servers.) I can see my skin, but they can't. It's really annoying because I just finished my custom skin of myself, AND NOBODY CAN SEE IT! If you need more details just ask.

What do I need to do to make my skin visible ?